# Custom block cannot hide under shipping method in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

Backend:

[image]

frontend

1.app/code/companyname/vendorname/view/frontend/web/template/delivery-date-block.html

```
<div id="delivery_datetime">
<label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
<div class="control">
    <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: true"   name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
</div>
<label class="label">Delivery Time</label>
<div class="control">
    <select  name="delivery_time" id="delivery_time" class="select"data-bind=" "></select>
</div>
<label class="label">Comment</label>
<div class="control">
    <textarea name="delivery_comment" id="delivery_comment"></textarea>
</div>
<br/>
</div>
```

2. app/code/companyname/vendorname/view/frontend/web/template/delivery-date-block.js

   ```
        define([
       'jquery',
       'ko',
       'uiComponent'
   ], function ($, ko, Component) {
       'use strict';
   console.log('its working');
    console.log(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.enable); 
       return Component.extend({
           defaults: {
               template: 'companyname_vendorname/delivery-date-block'
           },
           initialize: function () {
               this._super();
               var enable = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.enable;
               var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
               var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
               var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
               var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
               var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
               if(enable == 0){   // here i used a condition
                 $('#delivery_datetime').hide();
               }
               else{
               if(!format) {
                   format = 'yy-mm-dd';
               }
               var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                   return parseInt(item, 10);
               });
               ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
                   init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                       var $el = $(element);
                       //initialize datetimepicker
                       if(noday) {
                           var options = {
                               minDate: 0,
                               dateFormat:format,
                               hourMin: hourMin,
                               hourMax: hourMax
                           };
                       } else {
                           var options = {
                               minDate: 0,
                               dateFormat:format,
                               hourMin: hourMin,
                               hourMax: hourMax,
                               beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                   var day = date.getDay();
                                   if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                       return [false];
                                   } else {
                                       return [true];
                                   }
                               }
                           };
                       }

                       $el.datepicker(options);

                       var writable = valueAccessor();
                       if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                           var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                           if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                               writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                           } else {
                               return;
                           }
                       }
                       writable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
                   },
                   update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                       var widget = $(element).data("DatePicker");
                       //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                       if (widget) {
                           var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                           widget.date(date);
                       }
                   }
               };

               return this;
           }
           }

       });
   });
   ```

output:
[image]

Someone please help me to solve this issue

Comment: `if((enable =='1') || (enable == 1)){$('#delivery_datetime').hide();}`

Comment: I had the same issue so I reversed the condition to :
`if(enable != 0){   // here i used a condition
     // do stuff here
}
else{
     $('#delivery_datetime').hide();
}`

Comment: if(enable == false){$('#delivery_datetime').hide();}

Comment: I already tried it reverse its not happen @Amit Naraniwal

Comment: try : `if(enable){ //do stuff here }  else{ $('#delivery_datetime').hide(); }`
Most probably it will work.

Comment: @magefms With your  code  i get a error like [this](https://prnt.sc/mojvgi)

Comment: @amit bera  same as magefms    i got  a error like [this](https://prnt.sc/mojvgi)

Comment: no its not working @magefms

Comment: if (!enable) {
    $('#delivery_datetime').hide();
}

Comment: try that one it should work

Comment: no that not work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> app/code/companyname/vendorname/view/frontend/web/template/delivery-date-block.js

Add following method

```
isVisible: function () {
    var enabled = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.enabled);
    return enabled;
}
```

Whole class looks like:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('its working');
    console.log(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.enable);
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'companyname_vendorname/delivery-date-block'
        },
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            var enable = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.enable;
            var disabled = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.disabled;
            var noday = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.noday;
            var hourMin = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMin);
            var hourMax = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.hourMax);
            var format = window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.format;
            if(enable == 0){   // here i used a condition
                $('#delivery_datetime').hide();
            }
            else{
                if(!format) {
                    format = 'yy-mm-dd';
                }
                var disabledDay = disabled.split(",").map(function(item) {
                    return parseInt(item, 10);
                });
                ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
                    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
                        var $el = $(element);
                        //initialize datetimepicker
                        if(noday) {
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat:format,
                                hourMin: hourMin,
                                hourMax: hourMax
                            };
                        } else {
                            var options = {
                                minDate: 0,
                                dateFormat:format,
                                hourMin: hourMin,
                                hourMax: hourMax,
                                beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                    var day = date.getDay();
                                    if(disabledDay.indexOf(day) > -1) {
                                        return [false];
                                    } else {
                                        return [true];
                                    }
                                }
                            };
                        }

                        $el.datepicker(options);

                        var writable = valueAccessor();
                        if (!ko.isObservable(writable)) {
                            var propWriters = allBindingsAccessor()._ko_property_writers;
                            if (propWriters && propWriters.datetimepicker) {
                                writable = propWriters.datetimepicker;
                            } else {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        writable($(element).datepicker("getDate"));
                    },
                    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                        var widget = $(element).data("DatePicker");
                        //when the view model is updated, update the widget
                        if (widget) {
                            var date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
                            widget.date(date);
                        }
                    }
                };

                return this;
            }
        },
        isVisible: function () {
            var enabled = parseInt(window.checkoutConfig.shipping.delivery_date.enabled);
            return enabled;
        }
    });
});
```

> app/code/companyname/vendorname/view/frontend/web/template/delivery-date-block.html

```
<!-- ko if: isVisible() -->
    <div id="delivery_datetime">
        <label class="label">Delivery Date</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" data-bind="datepicker: true"   name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date" readonly="true"/>
        </div>
        <label class="label">Delivery Time</label>
        <div class="control">
            <select  name="delivery_time" id="delivery_time" class="select"data-bind=" "></select>
        </div>
        <label class="label">Comment</label>
        <div class="control">
            <textarea name="delivery_comment" id="delivery_comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br/>
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: its working what i expected thanks @Sohel Rana

Comment: I need a another help from you,  how to i  will show calendar icon with in the delivery date input field @sohel Rana